# What's the relationship between js-mode and js2-mode?

Tags: javascript, js2-mode

I saw there is a `js-mode` bundled in Emacs. I've also seen a [`js2-mode`](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode). However, I have also seen Emacs [git log](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?h=emacs-26&id=e562356c3f31bf96250bd3e8a7c50e8322b15d68) on `js-mode` refers to `js2-mode` bug reports. What is the relationship between them?

Comment: The js2-mode maintainer happens to have commit access to Emacs and therefore fixed an issue present in both of them. To not repeat themselves, a link explaining the problem was added. This isn't about their relationship, but rather the convenient thing to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what @wasamasa said, `js2-mode` derives from `js-mode` and shares its indentation engine.

Thus, fixing an indentation bug in `js-mode` fixes it in `js2-mode` as well.

Comment: Ah, so there is indeed a relationship between them, thanks for the info! For some reason I assumed indentation in js2-mode was a homebrew solution when reading about it on Steve Yegge's blog.

Comment: @wasamasa Even back then, it had a lot of common with indentation code in js-mode. Either by copying from it, or by copying from a common source.